# What is the correct Syntax for SQL Like Operator

Tags: sql

Glad if someone can advise me the correct syntax for line 3, the like operator.

TableB Column2 is substring of TableA Column1, (at Start/mid/end)

Thanks in Advance.  Toh

```
Merge tableA as A
using tableB as B
ON A.Column1 like B.Column2
when matched then
    update set 
    A.Column1= B.Column1,
    A.Column3= B.Column3,
    A.Column4= B.Column4,
    A.Column5= B.Column5
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Are you getting any error. Do you want to perform wildcard search ?

Answer (score 0):

You need wildcards:

```
ON A.Column1 like '%' || B.Column2  || '%'
```

In some databases, you would use `+` instead of `||` or the `concat()` function.

Comment: Hi Cordon, thanks for your help.  I need to perform wildcard search... and B.Column2 is a column name in Table B.  1) ON A.Column1 like B.Column2 + '%'  working fine data updated... 2) ON A.Column1 like ('%'+ B.Column2)... query executed successfully but data not updated.

Comment: 3) ON A.Column1 like ('%'+ B.Column2 + '%')... Error message : Msg 8672, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

Comment: Column2 of table B is a primary key and no duplicate checked and confirmed.

Comment: ON A.Column1 like '%' || B.Column2  || '%'  ... red wavy line below |